# "Enter" key calls a javascript function when textbox is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text box and a button

```
<div class="TextField Large">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="SearchBox" />
</div>
<div style="height: 40px; text-align: right; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;">
    <input type="button" value="Search" class="Button" onclick="Search()" />
</div>
```

Basically you enter a text in the textbox and when you click on the Search button a JavaScript function `Search()` is called.

How can I add the possibility that when the user enters a text and press "Enter" on the keyboard the Search is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Search(){
    alert("search!");
    //search logic
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="return Search()">
        <input type="text" name="q" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

That's all

Answer (score 2):

First: Add a form (this should have a server side fallback for whatever the JavaScript does).

Second: Change the button to a submit button.

Third: Move the JavaScript to the form's submit event instead of the button's client event.

Answer (score 1):

When your inputs are in a form enter should automatically submit the form,

otherwise:

```
$('your form').keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) $(this).submit();
});
```

I recommend you change your button to type="submit" though for that enter functionality to automatically work, then do your Search() code in a submit event handler

```
$('your form').submit(function() {
  // your search code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textbox').keypress(function(event){
   var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
   if(keycode == '13'){
      alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox');    
   }
});
```

Hopefully this will help you..